# How to work Yii2 csrf token in Angular2?

Tags: yii, yii2

I have create angular2 application and REST api in yii2.

Yii2 controller is **"yii\rest\Controller"**

Angularjs and Angular2 both are very different.

**I don't understand how to use CSRF token in angular2 post request.**

Angular2 and yii2 no any connection. only api call in yii2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [yii2:- how can i manage angularjs post request in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759426/yii2-how-can-i-manage-angularjs-post-request-in-yii2)

Comment: not duplicate...i think you have not knowledge about Angular2

Comment: "To retrieve token use yii.getCsrfToken(), but yii\web\YiiAsset asset must be registered. " -  that's all, not so hard to read.

Comment: Yii2 in develop only rest api then i have not getting yii.getCsrfToken()

Comment: develop full client side angular2 application.

Comment: So how exacly it should work? If it's not connected - there's no way to generate and pass CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

in your SiteController Add this function to show your csrf token

```
public function actionCsrf()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return [
        '_csrf' => Yii::$app->request->csrfToken
    ];
}
```

and add input type hidden in your form like
on html

```
<form>
...
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" id="_csrf" value="" />
...
</form>
```

make get ajax in your angular, its version on jquery
on javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        data : "",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        url : "http://localhost/app/web/site/csrf",
        success : function(result){
            var resultObj = result;
            document.getElementById("_csrf").value = resultObj._csrf;
        }
    });
</script>
```